# Server XMLHttp causes page in IE 8 to execute forever?

Tags: asp-classic

I have the following code from a page called Error1.asp. But whenever it runs, the page to which data is posted never shows up. What needs to show up is 'default1.aspx' but it never renders in IE8. In Firefox and Chrome it does render without any issues using the same code as below.
How can I make this ServerXMLHttp work in IE 8? I have Win 7 64-bit  on my computer.

```
Set xmlhttp = server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
xmlhttp.Open  "POST","http://localhost/ClassicASPErrorHandling/default1.aspx",false
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

xmlhttp.send   "errorDesc=" & Server.HTMLEncode(Server.GetLastError().Description() )& "&errorDetailedDesc=" & Server.HTMLEncode(Server.GetLastError().ASPDescription()) & "&errorURL=" & strURL & "&errorLineNumber=" & Server.HTMLEncode(ASPErr.Line()) & "&errorFile=" & Server.HTMLEncode( ASPErr.File()) & "&errorSource=" & Server.HTMLEncode(ASPErr.Source()) & "&logonUser="  & strLogonUser & "&errorCode=" & Server.HTMLEncode(Server.GetLastError().ASPCode() )
Response.Write xmlhttp.responseText
Response.ContentType = "text/xml"
Response.Write xmlhttp.responsexml.xml
Set xmlhttp = nothing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt this is a browser issue, i think what is happening is you are displaying content on the page, then changing the content type, IE may be having trouble understanding this, therefore, try this change in your code and see if it works out:

```
 Set xmlhttp = server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
 xmlhttp.Open  "POST","http://localhost/ClassicASPErrorHandling/default1.aspx",false
 xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

 xmlhttp.send   "errorDesc=" & Server.HTMLEncode(Server.GetLastError().Description() )& "&errorDetailedDesc=" & Server.HTMLEncode(Server.GetLastError().ASPDescription()) & "&errorURL=" & strURL & "&errorLineNumber=" & Server.HTMLEncode(ASPErr.Line()) & "&errorFile=" & Server.HTMLEncode( ASPErr.File()) & "&errorSource=" &      Server.HTMLEncode(ASPErr.Source()) & "&logonUser="  & strLogonUser & "&errorCode=" & Server.HTMLEncode(Server.GetLastError().ASPCode() )

 Response.ContentType = "text/xml" //THIS SHOULD HAPPEN BEFORE USING RESPONSE.WRITE

 Response.Write xmlhttp.responseText //DO NOT DO THIS UNLESS DATA IS XML BECAUSE OF CONTENTTYPE
 Response.Write xmlhttp.responsexml.xml
 Set xmlhttp = nothing
```

And if you're trying to display NON-XML data on a `ContentType = "text/xml"` page, i can assure you IE would probably be the first browser that would give issues.  Make sure the only content written to the page is XML or change your `ContentType = "text/html"`

Comment: I really appreciate your excellent answer. It solved my problem. I had to change to : Response.ContentType ="text/html" and also place the content type line before all writes. CAN YOU CLARIFY IF I NEED TO REMOVE THE LINE WHERE YOU COMMENTED '//DO NOT DO THIS UNLESS DATA IS XML....' ? I am now using 'text/html'. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 2):

An answer has already been accepted however for the benefit of other readers here is what the code *should* look like:-

```
 Dim xmlhttp: Set xmlhttp = server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP") 
 xmlhttp.Open "POST", "http://localhost/ClassicASPErrorHandling/default1.aspx", false 
 xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" 

 Dim lastErr: lastErr = Server.GetLastError()
 Dim entityBody: entityBody = "errorDesc=" & Server.URLEncode(lastErr.Description) _
      & "&errorDetailedDesc=" & Server.URLEncode(lastErr.ASPDescription) _
      & "&errorURL=" & Server.URLEncode(strURL) _
      & "&errorLineNumber=" & lastErr.Line _
      & "&errorFile=" & Server.URLEncode(lastErr.File) _
      & "&errorSource=" & Server.URLEncode(lastErr.Source) _
      & "&logonUser="  & strLogonUser _
      & "&errorCode=" & lastErr.ASPCode 

 xmlhttp.send Replace(entityBody, "+", "%20")

 Response.ContentType = "text/html"  

 Response.Write xmlhttp.responseText
```